# What can be substitution of maple syrup for pancakes?

Tags: substitutions

I live in India and maple syrup isn't available in my town. I don't like honey over my pancakes.

What could be the substitutes ?

I think sweetened cream would be good. Also, having it with ice cream seems like a good idea.

Comment: Sorry, but this kind of question is off topic on the site. You are basically asking what topping will taste well in combination with pancakes, and we don't do flavor combinations because they are subjective. I thought about removing the last paragraph and interpret it as a real substitution question, as in "what else will match the effects on both taste and texture", but this doesn't make much sense, because a topping doesn't have structural effects on the pancakes, and nothing beside maple syrup tastes like maple syrup.

Comment: For what it's worth, the simple answer is basically anything else sweet. There are tons of kinds of syrup, some fruit-based, some mostly just slightly flavored sugar, and then things like fruit preserves or compotes. Which you think is a good substitute is down to your personal preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maple syrup on pancakes is just a condiment, much like ketchup on a hamburger.

You can use any topping you like, or no topping at all.

Among the popular ones are:

- Butter
- Whipped cream
- Fruit, berries, or applesauce
- Jam or jelly
- Peanut butter

Comment: In India, you may be able to find Lyle's Golden Syrup, which would also work well.